# How can I create a Magento child theme?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm customizing a Magento 1.9.1 CE template, bought from themeforest.net. I know that I should create a child theme so the website can be updated easily, but I'm having some doubts.

This is the theme structure, using the template folder as an example:

```
app>design>frontend>theme-package>theme-option-1>template>*
```

So, isn't it a child theme already? How can I create my child theme?

Option 1:

```
app>design>frontend>theme-package>theme-option1>my-child-theme>template>*
```

Option 2:

```
app>design>frontend>theme-package>my-child-theme>template>*
```

Using the second option, wouldn't I be losing some configuration files from "theme-option-1"?

Comment: You can configure Magento to look for templates and layouts in a specific theme (your child theme) and if it doesn't find them there then fall back to another theme (the one you downloaded). This is just configuration in System -> Configuration -> Design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is incorrect, you can not set theme in magento like this way.

You need to follow Option 2. check below Screenshot for configure design tab in backend.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pankaj! I'll try that.